# Insert input fields value on button click in magento

Tags: ajax

I am new to magento. I am trying to insert textbox value into database on button click.
I used this code to insert value in database table...

```
$data = array('title'=>'hello there','content'=>'how are you? i am fine over here.','status'=>1);
$model = Mage::getModel('mynews/mynews')->setData($data);
try {
$insertId = $model->save()->getId();
echo "Data successfully inserted. Insert ID: ".$insertId;
} catch (Exception $e){
echo $e->getMessage(); 
}
```

but i want this on a button click. And it should take the values from textboxes.

Comment: follow these [tutorial](http://excellencemagentoblog.com/)

Comment: can get the post data in controller??  Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParams();

Answer (score 0):

You should give your input a name and have a button directing to this controller function:

```
function addDataAction()
{
     $data = $this->getRequest()->getParam('my_input_name', array());

    $model = Mage::getModel('mynews/mynews')->setData($data);
    try {
      $insertId = $model->save()->getId();
      Mage::log("Data successfully inserted. Insert ID: ".$insertId, null, 'my_log.log');
   } catch (Exception $e){
     $error = $e->getMessage(); 
     Mage::log($error, null, 'my_log_error.log');
   }
}
```

It should add data and also create log file with your message.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but will you please explain how to redirect to this controller function with textbox values on button click. I have tried this ajax code but it is not working.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
    
     jQuery( function() {
     jQuery("#savedb").click( function() {
     jQuery.ajax( {
    url: "<?php echo Mage::getUrl('modulename/index/methodname'); ?>",
     type: 'POST',
     async: false,
     dataType: 'text',
     processData: false,
     data: {
     a: $('#title').val(),
     b: $('#content').val(),
     c: $('#status').val()
     },
         });
     });
     });
      
     </script>